# Calculate a 2D homogeneous perspective transformation matrix from 4 points in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, transform, linear-algebra

I've got coordinates of 4 points in 2D that form a rectangle and their coordinates after a perspective transformation has been applied.

[image]

The perspective transformation is calculated in homogeneous coordinates and defined by a 3x3 matrix `M`. If the matrix is not known, how can I calculate it from the given points?

The calculation for one point would be:

```
| M11 M12 M13 |   | P1.x |   | w*P1'.x |
| M21 M22 M23 | * | P1.y | = | w*P1'.y |
| M31 M32 M33 |   | 1    |   | w*1     |
```

To calculate all points simultaneously I write them together in one matrix `A` and analogously for the transformed points in a matrix `B`:

```
    | P1.x P2.x P3.x P4.x |
A = | P1.y P2.y P3.y P4.y |
    | 1    1    1    1    |
```

So the equation is `M*A=B` and this can be solved for `M` in MATLAB by `M = B/A` or `M = (A'\B')'`.

But it's not that easy. I know the coordinates of the points after transformation, but I don't know the exact `B`, because there is the factor `w` and it's not necessary 1 after a homogeneous transformation. Cause in homogeneous coordinates every multiple of a vector is the same point and I don't know which multiple I'll get.

To take account of these unknown factors I write the equation as `M*A=B*W`
where `W` is a diagonal matrix with the factors w1...w4 for every point in `B` on the diagonal. So `A` and `B` are now completely known and I have to solve this equation for `M` and `W`.

If I could rearrange the equation into the form `x*A=B` or `A*x=B` where `x` would be something like `M*W` I could solve it and knowing the solution for `M*W` would maybe be enough already. However despite trying every possible rearrangement I didn't managed to do so. Until it hit me that encapsulating `(M*W)` would not be possible, since one is a 3x3 matrix and the other a 4x4 matrix. And here I'm stuck.

Also `M*A=B*W` does not have a single solution for `M`, because every multiple of `M` is the same transformation. Writing this as a system of linear equations one could simply fix one of the entries of `M` to get a single solution. Furthermore there might be inputs that have no solution for `M` at all, but let's not worry about this for now.

What I'm actually trying to achieve is some kind of vector graphics editing program where the user can drag the corners of a shape's bounding box to transform it, while internally the transformation matrix is calculated.

And actually I need this in JavaScript, but if I can't even solve this in MATLAB I'm completely stuck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Should have been an easy question. So how do I get `M*A=B*W` into a solvable form? It's just matrix multiplications, so we can write this as a system of linear equations. You know like: `M11*A11 + M12*A21 + M13*A31 = B11*W11 + B12*W21 + B13*W31 + B14*W41`. And every system of linear equations can be written in the form `Ax=b`, or to avoid confusion with already used variables in my question: `N*x=y`. That's all.

An example according to my question: I generate some input data with a known `M` and `W`:

```
M = [
    1 2 3;
    4 5 6;
    7 8 1
];
A = [
    0 0 1 1;
    0 1 0 1;
    1 1 1 1
];
W = [
    4 0 0 0;
    0 3 0 0;
    0 0 2 0;
    0 0 0 1
];
B = M*A*(W^-1);
```

Then I forget about `M` and `W`. Meaning I now have 13 variables I'm looking to solve. I rewrite `M*A=B*W` into a system of linear equations, and from there into the form `N*x=y`. In `N` every column has the factors for one variable:

```
N = [
    A(1,1) A(2,1) A(3,1)      0      0      0      0      0      0 -B(1,1)       0       0       0;
         0      0      0 A(1,1) A(2,1) A(3,1)      0      0      0 -B(2,1)       0       0       0;
         0      0      0      0      0      0 A(1,1) A(2,1) A(3,1) -B(3,1)       0       0       0;
    A(1,2) A(2,2) A(3,2)      0      0      0      0      0      0       0 -B(1,2)       0       0;
         0      0      0 A(1,2) A(2,2) A(3,2)      0      0      0       0 -B(2,2)       0       0;
         0      0      0      0      0      0 A(1,2) A(2,2) A(3,2)       0 -B(3,2)       0       0;
    A(1,3) A(2,3) A(3,3)      0      0      0      0      0      0       0       0 -B(1,3)       0;
         0      0      0 A(1,3) A(2,3) A(3,3)      0      0      0       0       0 -B(2,3)       0;
         0      0      0      0      0      0 A(1,3) A(2,3) A(3,3)       0       0 -B(3,3)       0;
    A(1,4) A(2,4) A(3,4)      0      0      0      0      0      0       0       0       0 -B(1,4);
         0      0      0 A(1,4) A(2,4) A(3,4)      0      0      0       0       0       0 -B(2,4);
         0      0      0      0      0      0 A(1,4) A(2,4) A(3,4)       0       0       0 -B(3,4);
         0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      1       0       0       0       0
];
```

And `y` is:

```
y = [ 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 1 ];
```

Notice the equation described by the last row in `N` whose solution is 1 according to `y`. That's what I mentioned in my question, you have to fix one of the entries of `M` to get a single solution. (We can do this because every multiple of `M` is the same transformation.) And with this equation I'm saying M33 should be 1.

We solve this for `x`:

```
x = N\y
```

and get:

```
x = [ 1.00000; 2.00000; 3.00000; 4.00000; 5.00000; 6.00000; 7.00000; 8.00000; 1.00000; 4.00000; 3.00000; 2.00000; 1.00000 ]
```

which are the solutions for `[ M11, M12, M13, M21, M22, M23, M31, M32, M33, w1, w2, w3, w4 ]`

`W` is not needed after `M` has been calculated. For a generic point `(x, y)`, the corresponding `w` is calculated while solving `x'` and `y'`.

```
| M11 M12 M13 |   | x |   | w * x' |
| M21 M22 M23 | * | y | = | w * y' |
| M31 M32 M33 |   | 1 |   | w * 1  |
```

When solving this in JavaScript I could use the [Numeric JavaScript](http://www.numericjs.com/) library which has the needed function [solve](http://www.numericjs.com/documentation.html) to solve Ax=b.

Answer (score 15):

OpenCV has a neat function that does this called [getPerspectiveTransform](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga15302cbff82bdcddb70158a58b73d981). The source code for this function is available [on github](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/11b020b9f9e111bddd40bffe3b1759aa02d966f0/modules/imgproc/src/imgwarp.cpp#L3001) with this description:

```
/* Calculates coefficients of perspective transformation
 * which maps (xi,yi) to (ui,vi), (i=1,2,3,4):
 *
 *      c00*xi + c01*yi + c02
 * ui = ---------------------
 *      c20*xi + c21*yi + c22
 *
 *      c10*xi + c11*yi + c12
 * vi = ---------------------
 *      c20*xi + c21*yi + c22
 *
 * Coefficients are calculated by solving linear system:
 * / x0 y0  1  0  0  0 -x0*u0 -y0*u0 \ /c00\ /u0\
 * | x1 y1  1  0  0  0 -x1*u1 -y1*u1 | |c01| |u1|
 * | x2 y2  1  0  0  0 -x2*u2 -y2*u2 | |c02| |u2|
 * | x3 y3  1  0  0  0 -x3*u3 -y3*u3 |.|c10|=|u3|,
 * |  0  0  0 x0 y0  1 -x0*v0 -y0*v0 | |c11| |v0|
 * |  0  0  0 x1 y1  1 -x1*v1 -y1*v1 | |c12| |v1|
 * |  0  0  0 x2 y2  1 -x2*v2 -y2*v2 | |c20| |v2|
 * \  0  0  0 x3 y3  1 -x3*v3 -y3*v3 / \c21/ \v3/
 *
 * where:
 *   cij - matrix coefficients, c22 = 1
 */
```

This system of equations is smaller as it avoids solving for `W` and `M33` (called `c22` by OpenCV). So how does it work? The linear system can be recreated by the following steps:

Start with the equation for one point:

```
| c00 c01 c02 |   | xi |   | w*ui |
| c10 c11 c12 | * | yi | = | w*vi |
| c20 c21 c22 |   | 1  |   | w*1  |
```

Convert this to a system of equations, solve `ui` and `vi`, and eliminate `w`. You get the formulas for projection transformation:

```
     c00*xi + c01*yi + c02
ui = ---------------------
     c20*xi + c21*yi + c22

     c10*xi + c11*yi + c12
vi = ---------------------
     c20*xi + c21*yi + c22
```

Multiply both sides with the denominator:

```
(c20*xi + c21*yi + c22) * ui = c00*xi + c01*yi + c02
(c20*xi + c21*yi + c22) * vi = c10*xi + c11*yi + c12
```

Distribute `ui` and `vi`:

```
c20*xi*ui + c21*yi*ui + c22*ui = c00*xi + c01*yi + c02
c20*xi*vi + c21*yi*vi + c22*vi = c10*xi + c11*yi + c12
```

Assume `c22 = 1`:

```
c20*xi*ui + c21*yi*ui + ui = c00*xi + c01*yi + c02
c20*xi*vi + c21*yi*vi + vi = c10*xi + c11*yi + c12
```

Collect all `cij` on the left hand side:

```
c00*xi + c01*yi + c02 - c20*xi*ui - c21*yi*ui = ui
c10*xi + c11*yi + c12 - c20*xi*vi - c21*yi*vi = vi
```

And finally convert to matrix form for four pairs of points:

```
/ x0 y0  1  0  0  0 -x0*u0 -y0*u0 \ /c00\ /u0\
| x1 y1  1  0  0  0 -x1*u1 -y1*u1 | |c01| |u1|
| x2 y2  1  0  0  0 -x2*u2 -y2*u2 | |c02| |u2|
| x3 y3  1  0  0  0 -x3*u3 -y3*u3 |.|c10|=|u3|
|  0  0  0 x0 y0  1 -x0*v0 -y0*v0 | |c11| |v0|
|  0  0  0 x1 y1  1 -x1*v1 -y1*v1 | |c12| |v1|
|  0  0  0 x2 y2  1 -x2*v2 -y2*v2 | |c20| |v2|
\  0  0  0 x3 y3  1 -x3*v3 -y3*v3 / \c21/ \v3/
```

This is now in the form of `Ax=b` and the solution can be obtained with `x = A\b`. Remember that `c22 = 1`.

Answer (score 1):

```
function T = calculatePerspectiveTransformMatrix(srcPts, destPts)
    % Check if the input points are valid
    if size(srcPts, 1) ~= 4 || size(destPts, 1) ~= 4
        error('Both source and destination points must have 4 rows');
    end

    % Construct the coefficient matrix A
    A = zeros(8, 8);
    b = zeros(8, 1);
    for i = 1:4
        A(i*2-1, :) = [srcPts(i, 1), srcPts(i, 2), 1, 0, 0, 0, -srcPts(i, 1)*destPts(i, 1), -srcPts(i, 2)*destPts(i, 1)];
        A(i*2, :) = [0, 0, 0, srcPts(i, 1), srcPts(i, 2), 1, -srcPts(i, 1)*destPts(i, 2), -srcPts(i, 2)*destPts(i, 2)];
        b(i*2-1:i*2) = [destPts(i, 1); destPts(i, 2)];
    end

    % Solve the linear system to obtain the perspective transform matrix
    x = A \ b;
    T = reshape([x; 1], [3, 3])';

    % Normalize the matrix
    T = T / T(3, 3);
end
```

To use this function, you can pass in two sets of corresponding points as input arguments (srcPts and destPts). Each set of points should be a matrix with four rows and two columns, where each row represents the x and y coordinates of a point.

For example, you can call the function like this:

```
srcPts = [10, 20; 30, 40; 50, 60; 70, 80];
destPts = [100, 200; 300, 400; 500, 600; 700, 800];

T = calculatePerspectiveTransformMatrix(srcPts, destPts);
```

The function will return a 3x3 perspective transform matrix T that maps the source points to the destination points.