# Shifting the coordinates of one pixel

Tags: c++, opencv, fpga, vivado-hls

I am trying to make a prototype for an algorithm to find the coordinates of a ball on a plate, and I want to make it as efficient as possible because I have to implement it in an FPGA. The pictures of the ball and plate are not always in the same orientation, so I need to shift the coordinates of the center of the ball, based on the coordinates of the corners of the plate.

To get an understanding what I mean, see the image below where the white sheet represents the plate.

[image]

Now I have already found a way to determine the coordinates of the ball on the picture, and the coordinates of the corners of the plate in the picture, but I want to find out where the ball is located on the plate.

I tried to do some things with getPerspectiveTransform() and wrapPerspective() and it worked, but this involves a lot of matrix computations and I think this is a bit overkill when I just want to shift the coordinates of one pixel (the center of the ball).

Do you know a more efficient way on how I can **determine the coordinates of the center pixel of the ball on the plate**?

Comment: Determine the algorithm to find this information first, then call the appropriate code to accomplish that algorithm. It looks like if you assume 1) the paper is rectangular, 2) the ball touches the paper at a point, 3) the paper is flat (close enough), 4) the ball is perfectly spherical, and 5) you know the focal distance of the camera, then you can start to figure out on paper (a different piece of paper, with a pencil) what is needed. Right?

Comment: Camera perspective will stay in this position like in the pic ? I think camera should take position parallel to plate ?

Comment: The camera can be placed within a range from -45° and 45° from the plate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using the answer of morotspaj of the post below and Matlab.

[Calculate a 2D homogeneous perspective transformation matrix from 4 points in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35819142/calculate-a-2d-homogeneous-perspective-transformation-matrix-from-4-points-in-ma)

ui and vi are already known (these equal the resolution of the picture), so I filled them into the 8x8 matrix and got the following:

```
/ x0 y0  1  0  0  0     0          0    \ /m00\ /  0  \
| x1 y1  1  0  0  0 -x1*RES_H -y1*RES_H | |m01| |RES_H|
| x2 y2  1  0  0  0     0          0    | |m02| |  0  |
| x3 y3  1  0  0  0 -x3*RES_H -y3*RES_H |.|m10|=|RES_H|
|  0  0  0 x0 y0  1     0          0    | |m11| |  0  |
|  0  0  0 x1 y1  1     0          0    | |m12| |  0  |
|  0  0  0 x2 y2  1 -x2*RES_V -y2*RES_V | |m20| |RES_V|
\  0  0  0 x3 y3  1 -x3*RES_V -y3*RES_V / \m21/ \RES_V/
```

Where RES_H = (640 - 1) and RES_V = (480 - 1). This equation can be seen as **Ax**=**b**. I putted the **A** matrix (8x8) and the **b** vector (8x1) in Matlab and used linsolve(**A**,**b**) to solve the linear system:

```
syms x0 x1 x2 x3 y0 y1 y2 y3 RES_H RES_V;
A = [ x0 y0 1 0 0 0 0 0 ; x1 y1 1 0 0 0 -x1*RES_H -y1*RES_H ; x2 y2 1 0 0 0 0 0 ; x3 y3 1  0 0 0 -x3*RES_H -y3*RES_H ; 0 0 0 x0 y0 1 0 0 ; 0 0 0 x1 y1 1 0 0 ; 0 0 0 x2 y2 1 -x2*RES_V -y2*RES_V ; 0 0 0 x3 y3 1 -x3*RES_V -y3*RES_V ];
b = [ 0 ; RES_H ; 0 ; RES_H ; 0 ; 0 ; RES_V ; RES_V ];
simplify(linsolve(A,B))
```

The result was the following:

```
m00 = -(RES_H*(y0 - y2)*(x0*y1 - x1*y0 - x0*y3 + x3*y0 + x1*y3 - x3*y1)*(x1*y2 - x2*y1 - x1*y3 + x3*y1 + x2*y3 - x3*y2))/(- x0*x0*x1*y1*y2*y2 + 2*x0*x0*x1*y1*y2*y3 - x0*x0*x1*y1*y3*y3 + x0*x0*x2*y1*y1*y2 - 2*x0*x0*x2*y1*y2*y3 + x0*x0*x2*y2*y3*y3 - 2*x0*x0*x3*y1*y1*y2 + x0*x0*x3*y1*y1*y3 + 2*x0*x0*x3*y1*y2*y2 - x0*x0*x3*y2*y2*y3 + x0*x1*x1*y0*y2*y2 - 2*x0*x1*x1*y0*y2*y3 + x0*x1*x1*y0*y3*y3 - 2*x0*x1*x2*y0*y1*y3 + 2*x0*x1*x2*y0*y2*y3 + 2*x0*x1*x2*y1*y3*y3 - 2*x0*x1*x2*y2*y3*y3 + 2*x0*x1*x3*y0*y1*y2 - 2*x0*x1*x3*y0*y2*y2 - 2*x0*x1*x3*y1*y2*y3 + 2*x0*x1*x3*y2*y2*y3 - x0*x2*x2*y0*y1*y1 + 2*x0*x2*x2*y0*y1*y3 - x0*x2*x2*y0*y3*y3 + 2*x0*x2*x3*y0*y1*y1 - 2*x0*x2*x3*y0*y1*y2 - 2*x0*x2*x3*y1*y1*y3 + 2*x0*x2*x3*y1*y2*y3 - x0*x3*x3*y0*y1*y1 + x0*x3*x3*y0*y2*y2 + 2*x0*x3*x3*y1*y1*y2 - 2*x0*x3*x3*y1*y2*y2 - x1*x1*x2*y0*y0*y2 + 2*x1*x1*x2*y0*y0*y3 - 2*x1*x1*x2*y0*y3*y3 + x1*x1*x2*y2*y3*y3 - x1*x1*x3*y0*y0*y3 + 2*x1*x1*x3*y0*y2*y3 - x1*x1*x3*y2*y2*y3 + x1*x2*x2*y0*y0*y1 - 2*x1*x2*x2*y0*y0*y3 + 2*x1*x2*x2*y0*y3*y3 - x1*x2*x2*y1*y3*y3 - 2*x1*x2*x3*y0*y0*y1 + 2*x1*x2*x3*y0*y0*y2 + 2*x1*x2*x3*y0*y1*y3 - 2*x1*x2*x3*y0*y2*y3 + x1*x3*x3*y0*y0*y1 - 2*x1*x3*x3*y0*y1*y2 + x1*x3*x3*y1*y2*y2 + x2*x2*x3*y0*y0*y3 - 2*x2*x2*x3*y0*y1*y3 + x2*x2*x3*y1*y1*y3 - x2*x3*x3*y0*y0*y2 + 2*x2*x3*x3*y0*y1*y2 - x2*x3*x3*y1*y1*y2);
m01 = (RES_H*(x0 - x2)*(x0*y1 - x1*y0 - x0*y3 + x3*y0 + x1*y3 - x3*y1)*(x1*y2 - x2*y1 - x1*y3 + x3*y1 + x2*y3 - x3*y2))/(- x0*x0*x1*y1*y2*y2 + 2*x0*x0*x1*y1*y2*y3 - x0*x0*x1*y1*y3*y3 + x0*x0*x2*y1*y1*y2 - 2*x0*x0*x2*y1*y2*y3 + x0*x0*x2*y2*y3*y3 - 2*x0*x0*x3*y1*y1*y2 + x0*x0*x3*y1*y1*y3 + 2*x0*x0*x3*y1*y2*y2 - x0*x0*x3*y2*y2*y3 + x0*x1*x1*y0*y2*y2 - 2*x0*x1*x1*y0*y2*y3 + x0*x1*x1*y0*y3*y3 - 2*x0*x1*x2*y0*y1*y3 + 2*x0*x1*x2*y0*y2*y3 + 2*x0*x1*x2*y1*y3*y3 - 2*x0*x1*x2*y2*y3*y3 + 2*x0*x1*x3*y0*y1*y2 - 2*x0*x1*x3*y0*y2*y2 - 2*x0*x1*x3*y1*y2*y3 + 2*x0*x1*x3*y2*y2*y3 - x0*x2*x2*y0*y1*y1 + 2*x0*x2*x2*y0*y1*y3 - x0*x2*x2*y0*y3*y3 + 2*x0*x2*x3*y0*y1*y1 - 2*x0*x2*x3*y0*y1*y2 - 2*x0*x2*x3*y1*y1*y3 + 2*x0*x2*x3*y1*y2*y3 - x0*x3*x3*y0*y1*y1 + x0*x3*x3*y0*y2*y2 + 2*x0*x3*x3*y1*y1*y2 - 2*x0*x3*x3*y1*y2*y2 - x1*x1*x2*y0*y0*y2 + 2*x1*x1*x2*y0*y0*y3 - 2*x1*x1*x2*y0*y3*y3 + x1*x1*x2*y2*y3*y3 - x1*x1*x3*y0*y0*y3 + 2*x1*x1*x3*y0*y2*y3 - x1*x1*x3*y2*y2*y3 + x1*x2*x2*y0*y0*y1 - 2*x1*x2*x2*y0*y0*y3 + 2*x1*x2*x2*y0*y3*y3 - x1*x2*x2*y1*y3*y3 - 2*x1*x2*x3*y0*y0*y1 + 2*x1*x2*x3*y0*y0*y2 + 2*x1*x2*x3*y0*y1*y3 - 2*x1*x2*x3*y0*y2*y3 + x1*x3*x3*y0*y0*y1 - 2*x1*x3*x3*y0*y1*y2 + x1*x3*x3*y1*y2*y2 + x2*x2*x3*y0*y0*y3 - 2*x2*x2*x3*y0*y1*y3 + x2*x2*x3*y1*y1*y3 - x2*x3*x3*y0*y0*y2 + 2*x2*x3*x3*y0*y1*y2 - x2*x3*x3*y1*y1*y2);
m02 = -(RES_H*(x0*y2 - x2*y0)*(x0*y1 - x1*y0 - x0*y3 + x3*y0 + x1*y3 - x3*y1)*(x1*y2 - x2*y1 - x1*y3 + x3*y1 + x2*y3 - x3*y2))/(- x0*x0*x1*y1*y2*y2 + 2*x0*x0*x1*y1*y2*y3 - x0*x0*x1*y1*y3*y3 + x0*x0*x2*y1*y1*y2 - 2*x0*x0*x2*y1*y2*y3 + x0*x0*x2*y2*y3*y3 - 2*x0*x0*x3*y1*y1*y2 + x0*x0*x3*y1*y1*y3 + 2*x0*x0*x3*y1*y2*y2 - x0*x0*x3*y2*y2*y3 + x0*x1*x1*y0*y2*y2 - 2*x0*x1*x1*y0*y2*y3 + x0*x1*x1*y0*y3*y3 - 2*x0*x1*x2*y0*y1*y3 + 2*x0*x1*x2*y0*y2*y3 + 2*x0*x1*x2*y1*y3*y3 - 2*x0*x1*x2*y2*y3*y3 + 2*x0*x1*x3*y0*y1*y2 - 2*x0*x1*x3*y0*y2*y2 - 2*x0*x1*x3*y1*y2*y3 + 2*x0*x1*x3*y2*y2*y3 - x0*x2*x2*y0*y1*y1 + 2*x0*x2*x2*y0*y1*y3 - x0*x2*x2*y0*y3*y3 + 2*x0*x2*x3*y0*y1*y1 - 2*x0*x2*x3*y0*y1*y2 - 2*x0*x2*x3*y1*y1*y3 + 2*x0*x2*x3*y1*y2*y3 - x0*x3*x3*y0*y1*y1 + x0*x3*x3*y0*y2*y2 + 2*x0*x3*x3*y1*y1*y2 - 2*x0*x3*x3*y1*y2*y2 - x1*x1*x2*y0*y0*y2 + 2*x1*x1*x2*y0*y0*y3 - 2*x1*x1*x2*y0*y3*y3 + x1*x1*x2*y2*y3*y3 - x1*x1*x3*y0*y0*y3 + 2*x1*x1*x3*y0*y2*y3 - x1*x1*x3*y2*y2*y3 + x1*x2*x2*y0*y0*y1 - 2*x1*x2*x2*y0*y0*y3 + 2*x1*x2*x2*y0*y3*y3 - x1*x2*x2*y1*y3*y3 - 2*x1*x2*x3*y0*y0*y1 + 2*x1*x2*x3*y0*y0*y2 + 2*x1*x2*x3*y0*y1*y3 - 2*x1*x2*x3*y0*y2*y3 + x1*x3*x3*y0*y0*y1 - 2*x1*x3*x3*y0*y1*y2 + x1*x3*x3*y1*y2*y2 + x2*x2*x3*y0*y0*y3 - 2*x2*x2*x3*y0*y1*y3 + x2*x2*x3*y1*y1*y3 - x2*x3*x3*y0*y0*y2 + 2*x2*x3*x3*y0*y1*y2 - x2*x3*x3*y1*y1*y2);
m10 = -(RES_V*(y0 - y1)*(x0*y2 - x2*y0 - x0*y3 + x3*y0 + x2*y3 - x3*y2)*(x1*y2 - x2*y1 - x1*y3 + x3*y1 + x2*y3 - x3*y2))/(- x0*x0*x1*y1*y2*y2 + 2*x0*x0*x1*y1*y2*y3 - x0*x0*x1*y1*y3*y3 + x0*x0*x2*y1*y1*y2 - 2*x0*x0*x2*y1*y2*y3 + x0*x0*x2*y2*y3*y3 - 2*x0*x0*x3*y1*y1*y2 + x0*x0*x3*y1*y1*y3 + 2*x0*x0*x3*y1*y2*y2 - x0*x0*x3*y2*y2*y3 + x0*x1*x1*y0*y2*y2 - 2*x0*x1*x1*y0*y2*y3 + x0*x1*x1*y0*y3*y3 - 2*x0*x1*x2*y0*y1*y3 + 2*x0*x1*x2*y0*y2*y3 + 2*x0*x1*x2*y1*y3*y3 - 2*x0*x1*x2*y2*y3*y3 + 2*x0*x1*x3*y0*y1*y2 - 2*x0*x1*x3*y0*y2*y2 - 2*x0*x1*x3*y1*y2*y3 + 2*x0*x1*x3*y2*y2*y3 - x0*x2*x2*y0*y1*y1 + 2*x0*x2*x2*y0*y1*y3 - x0*x2*x2*y0*y3*y3 + 2*x0*x2*x3*y0*y1*y1 - 2*x0*x2*x3*y0*y1*y2 - 2*x0*x2*x3*y1*y1*y3 + 2*x0*x2*x3*y1*y2*y3 - x0*x3*x3*y0*y1*y1 + x0*x3*x3*y0*y2*y2 + 2*x0*x3*x3*y1*y1*y2 - 2*x0*x3*x3*y1*y2*y2 - x1*x1*x2*y0*y0*y2 + 2*x1*x1*x2*y0*y0*y3 - 2*x1*x1*x2*y0*y3*y3 + x1*x1*x2*y2*y3*y3 - x1*x1*x3*y0*y0*y3 + 2*x1*x1*x3*y0*y2*y3 - x1*x1*x3*y2*y2*y3 + x1*x2*x2*y0*y0*y1 - 2*x1*x2*x2*y0*y0*y3 + 2*x1*x2*x2*y0*y3*y3 - x1*x2*x2*y1*y3*y3 - 2*x1*x2*x3*y0*y0*y1 + 2*x1*x2*x3*y0*y0*y2 + 2*x1*x2*x3*y0*y1*y3 - 2*x1*x2*x3*y0*y2*y3 + x1*x3*x3*y0*y0*y1 - 2*x1*x3*x3*y0*y1*y2 + x1*x3*x3*y1*y2*y2 + x2*x2*x3*y0*y0*y3 - 2*x2*x2*x3*y0*y1*y3 + x2*x2*x3*y1*y1*y3 - x2*x3*x3*y0*y0*y2 + 2*x2*x3*x3*y0*y1*y2 - x2*x3*x3*y1*y1*y2);
m11 = (RES_V*(x0 - x1)*(x0*y2 - x2*y0 - x0*y3 + x3*y0 + x2*y3 - x3*y2)*(x1*y2 - x2*y1 - x1*y3 + x3*y1 + x2*y3 - x3*y2))/(- x0*x0*x1*y1*y2*y2 + 2*x0*x0*x1*y1*y2*y3 - x0*x0*x1*y1*y3*y3 + x0*x0*x2*y1*y1*y2 - 2*x0*x0*x2*y1*y2*y3 + x0*x0*x2*y2*y3*y3 - 2*x0*x0*x3*y1*y1*y2 + x0*x0*x3*y1*y1*y3 + 2*x0*x0*x3*y1*y2*y2 - x0*x0*x3*y2*y2*y3 + x0*x1*x1*y0*y2*y2 - 2*x0*x1*x1*y0*y2*y3 + x0*x1*x1*y0*y3*y3 - 2*x0*x1*x2*y0*y1*y3 + 2*x0*x1*x2*y0*y2*y3 + 2*x0*x1*x2*y1*y3*y3 - 2*x0*x1*x2*y2*y3*y3 + 2*x0*x1*x3*y0*y1*y2 - 2*x0*x1*x3*y0*y2*y2 - 2*x0*x1*x3*y1*y2*y3 + 2*x0*x1*x3*y2*y2*y3 - x0*x2*x2*y0*y1*y1 + 2*x0*x2*x2*y0*y1*y3 - x0*x2*x2*y0*y3*y3 + 2*x0*x2*x3*y0*y1*y1 - 2*x0*x2*x3*y0*y1*y2 - 2*x0*x2*x3*y1*y1*y3 + 2*x0*x2*x3*y1*y2*y3 - x0*x3*x3*y0*y1*y1 + x0*x3*x3*y0*y2*y2 + 2*x0*x3*x3*y1*y1*y2 - 2*x0*x3*x3*y1*y2*y2 - x1*x1*x2*y0*y0*y2 + 2*x1*x1*x2*y0*y0*y3 - 2*x1*x1*x2*y0*y3*y3 + x1*x1*x2*y2*y3*y3 - x1*x1*x3*y0*y0*y3 + 2*x1*x1*x3*y0*y2*y3 - x1*x1*x3*y2*y2*y3 + x1*x2*x2*y0*y0*y1 - 2*x1*x2*x2*y0*y0*y3 + 2*x1*x2*x2*y0*y3*y3 - x1*x2*x2*y1*y3*y3 - 2*x1*x2*x3*y0*y0*y1 + 2*x1*x2*x3*y0*y0*y2 + 2*x1*x2*x3*y0*y1*y3 - 2*x1*x2*x3*y0*y2*y3 + x1*x3*x3*y0*y0*y1 - 2*x1*x3*x3*y0*y1*y2 + x1*x3*x3*y1*y2*y2 + x2*x2*x3*y0*y0*y3 - 2*x2*x2*x3*y0*y1*y3 + x2*x2*x3*y1*y1*y3 - x2*x3*x3*y0*y0*y2 + 2*x2*x3*x3*y0*y1*y2 - x2*x3*x3*y1*y1*y2);
m12 = -(RES_V*(x0*y1 - x1*y0)*(x0*y2 - x2*y0 - x0*y3 + x3*y0 + x2*y3 - x3*y2)*(x1*y2 - x2*y1 - x1*y3 + x3*y1 + x2*y3 - x3*y2))/(- x0*x0*x1*y1*y2*y2 + 2*x0*x0*x1*y1*y2*y3 - x0*x0*x1*y1*y3*y3 + x0*x0*x2*y1*y1*y2 - 2*x0*x0*x2*y1*y2*y3 + x0*x0*x2*y2*y3*y3 - 2*x0*x0*x3*y1*y1*y2 + x0*x0*x3*y1*y1*y3 + 2*x0*x0*x3*y1*y2*y2 - x0*x0*x3*y2*y2*y3 + x0*x1*x1*y0*y2*y2 - 2*x0*x1*x1*y0*y2*y3 + x0*x1*x1*y0*y3*y3 - 2*x0*x1*x2*y0*y1*y3 + 2*x0*x1*x2*y0*y2*y3 + 2*x0*x1*x2*y1*y3*y3 - 2*x0*x1*x2*y2*y3*y3 + 2*x0*x1*x3*y0*y1*y2 - 2*x0*x1*x3*y0*y2*y2 - 2*x0*x1*x3*y1*y2*y3 + 2*x0*x1*x3*y2*y2*y3 - x0*x2*x2*y0*y1*y1 + 2*x0*x2*x2*y0*y1*y3 - x0*x2*x2*y0*y3*y3 + 2*x0*x2*x3*y0*y1*y1 - 2*x0*x2*x3*y0*y1*y2 - 2*x0*x2*x3*y1*y1*y3 + 2*x0*x2*x3*y1*y2*y3 - x0*x3*x3*y0*y1*y1 + x0*x3*x3*y0*y2*y2 + 2*x0*x3*x3*y1*y1*y2 - 2*x0*x3*x3*y1*y2*y2 - x1*x1*x2*y0*y0*y2 + 2*x1*x1*x2*y0*y0*y3 - 2*x1*x1*x2*y0*y3*y3 + x1*x1*x2*y2*y3*y3 - x1*x1*x3*y0*y0*y3 + 2*x1*x1*x3*y0*y2*y3 - x1*x1*x3*y2*y2*y3 + x1*x2*x2*y0*y0*y1 - 2*x1*x2*x2*y0*y0*y3 + 2*x1*x2*x2*y0*y3*y3 - x1*x2*x2*y1*y3*y3 - 2*x1*x2*x3*y0*y0*y1 + 2*x1*x2*x3*y0*y0*y2 + 2*x1*x2*x3*y0*y1*y3 - 2*x1*x2*x3*y0*y2*y3 + x1*x3*x3*y0*y0*y1 - 2*x1*x3*x3*y0*y1*y2 + x1*x3*x3*y1*y2*y2 + x2*x2*x3*y0*y0*y3 - 2*x2*x2*x3*y0*y1*y3 + x2*x2*x3*y1*y1*y3 - x2*x3*x3*y0*y0*y2 + 2*x2*x3*x3*y0*y1*y2 - x2*x3*x3*y1*y1*y2);
```

Using m00, m01, m02, m10, m11 and m12, I constructed an M matrix. I omitted m20, m21 and m22 because they have no influence on the result of x and y.

Finally, I used this M matrix to shift the coordinates of the ball:

```
x_shifted = m00*x + m01*y + m02;
y_shifted = m10*x + m11*y + m12;
```

Which is based on this:

[image]

As you can see, the solution produced by Matlab results in extremely long equations. By accident, I found out when you swap xi with ui and yi with vi in the **A** matrix, you will get the inverse of the transformation matrix **M** for m00, m01, m02, m10, m11, m12, but the coefficients are computed with way shorter equations.

```
/   0     0     1     0     0     0     0         0     \ /m00\ /x0\
| RES_H   0     1     0     0     0 -RES_H*x1     0     | |m01| |x1|
|   0   RES_V   1     0     0     0     0     -RES_V*x2 | |m02| |x2|
| RES_H RES_V   1     0     0     0 -RES_H*x3 -RES_V*x3 |.|m10|=|x3|
|   0     0     0     0     0     1     0         0     | |m11| |y0|
|   0     0     0   RES_H   0     1 -RES_H*y1     0     | |m12| |y1|
|   0     0     0     0   RES_V   1     0     -RES_V*y2 | |m20| |y2|
\   0     0     0   RES_H RES_V   1 -RES_H*y3 -RES_V*y3 / \m21/ \y3/
```

When you let this solve by Matlab in the same way, you will get:

```
m00 = (x0*x2*y1 - x1*x2*y0 - x0*x3*y1 + x1*x3*y0 - x0*x2*y3 + x0*x3*y2 + x1*x2*y3 - x1*x3*y2)/(RES_H*(x1*y2 - x2*y1 - x1*y3 + x3*y1 + x2*y3 - x3*y2));
m01 = -(x0*x1*y2 - x1*x2*y0 - x0*x1*y3 + x0*x3*y1 - x0*x3*y2 + x2*x3*y0 + x1*x2*y3 - x2*x3*y1)/(RES_V*(x1*y2 - x2*y1 - x1*y3 + x3*y1 + x2*y3 - x3*y2));
m02 = x0;
m10 = (x0*y1*y2 - x1*y0*y2 - x0*y1*y3 + x1*y0*y3 - x2*y0*y3 + x3*y0*y2 + x2*y1*y3 - x3*y1*y2)/(RES_H*(x1*y2 - x2*y1 - x1*y3 + x3*y1 + x2*y3 - x3*y2));
m11 = -(x0*y1*y2 - x2*y0*y1 - x1*y0*y3 + x3*y0*y1 - x0*y2*y3 + x2*y0*y3 + x1*y2*y3 - x3*y1*y2)/(RES_V*(x1*y2 - x2*y1 - x1*y3 + x3*y1 + x2*y3 - x3*y2));
m12 = y0;
m20 = (x0*y2 - x2*y0 - x0*y3 - x1*y2 + x2*y1 + x3*y0 + x1*y3 - x3*y1)/(RES_H*(x1*y2 - x2*y1 - x1*y3 + x3*y1 + x2*y3 - x3*y2));
m21 = -(x0*y1 - x1*y0 - x0*y3 + x1*y2 - x2*y1 + x3*y0 + x2*y3 - x3*y2)/(RES_V*(x1*y2 - x2*y1 - x1*y3 + x3*y1 + x2*y3 - x3*y2));
m22 = 1.0;
```

When you put these coefficients into a matrix and invert this matrix, you will get the same results for m00, m01, m02, m10, m11, m12 as for the first method.

I used the program which I found here to invert the matrix:
https://codingtech2017.wordpress.com/2017/05/03/c-program-to-inverse-a-matrix3x3/

Answer (score 0):

Opencv's getPerspectiveTransform returns a 3x3 transformation matrix. All warpPerspective does is take the x,y coordinates of each pixel and multiply it with that matrix (augmenting [x,y] -> [x,y,1]).

If you want to just modify just one point P [x,y,1], then given the transformation matrix M, you can transform the point using:

```
numpy.matmul(M, P);
```

Here's some example code showing how it works. We make four example points and show that warping them using matmul is equivalent to using warpPerspective.

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

# test points
pts1 = np.float32([[56,65],[368,52],[28,387],[389,390]]);
pts2 = np.float32([[0,0],[300,0],[0,300],[300,300]]);

# transformation
M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts1,pts2);

# if our method works, then transforming each pts1 with M
# should result in pts2
transformed_points = [];
for p in pts1:
    # augment point
    point = np.array([p[0], p[1], 1], dtype = np.float32);

    # multiply
    transformed = np.matmul(M, point);

    # unpack and clean up
    x, y, scale = transformed;
    x /= scale;
    y /= scale;
    x = round(x, 5); # to clear out long floating points
    y = round(y, 5);
    transformed_points.append([x,y]);

# compare points
for a in range(len(pts2)):
    print("Target: " + str(pts2[a]));
    print("Transformed: " + str(transformed_points[a]));
```

Comment: The problem is that getPerspectiveTransform is not a standard function which is available on FPGA platforms. It is also verry inefficient to implement in an FPGA, because it determines the transformation matrix by solving a 8x8 matrix.

Comment: ahh, sorry I misunderstood the issue.